# How to make a Jquery filter for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a really big table and want to create a filter with jquery for it. Basically, I want to make something like this. Watch the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        if ($("#checkbox1").is(':checked'))
            $(".anglu").show();
        else
            $(".anglu").hide();
    });
});
```

[image]

My code looks something like this. However, It takes a lot of time to write every class for every table. Maybe I could do It quicker way? Also, this Jquery doesn't work for some reason. Any Ideas?

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gidas</th>
            <th>Kategorija</th>
            <th>Kalbos</th>
            <th>Veda po salis</th>
            <th>Kontaktai</th>
            <th>E-pastas</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="anglu">
        <td>Akucevičiūtė, Jūratė</td>
        <td>Aukščiausia - Ekspertas</td>
        <td>Anglu</td>
        <td>Italija</td>
        <td>+370564845698</td>
        <td>rutasiogoliavaitegmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Abaravičiūtė, Rūta</td>
        <td>Antra</td>
        <td>Rusų</td>
        <td>Estija, Islandija, Latvija, Lietuva</td>
        <td>+37056965698</td>
        <td>geramoerishotmail.lt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Arlauskienė, Vitalija</td>
        <td>Pirma</td>
        <td>Lenku</td>
        <td>Estija, Latvija, Lenkija, Lietuva, Liuksemburgas, Nyderlandai, Suomija, Švedija</td>
        <td>+37056568698</td>
        <td>gomuriotiesapastininkas.lt</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you know about the DataTable Plugin.? You can do this type tables easyly. It has lots of beautiful features.

Comment: No, I didn't. Maybe you can tell me a bit more about it? ;) @SayedRafeeq

Comment: Yeah, There is one error. js?sensor=false:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null.

Comment: Dont really know what it  says. @IsabelInc

Comment: Like everyone has stated its a good idea to use a plugin but it's good practice if you want to build your own.

Comment: I would be pretty satisfied with a plugin. The problem is that Im pretty new to Jquery and js. But I need to finish my project really soon and this filter is my biggest wall that I can not surpass. Also, I'm searcheing for different plugins but dont really understand them. Could you please at least send me a link. I would be pleased. @IsabelInc

Comment: Data table seems like a solid plugin that does what you want. https://datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you a ton. Hovewer, this site does not contain anything with checkbox filtering... @IsabelInc

Comment: It wouldnt be too hard to get the values of the check box and pass them to the plugin using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick way I would do it:

Setup the tables with appropriate classes and IDs to be selected easily:

```html
<div id="country-filters">
<input type="checkbox" id="filter-united_states" value="United States" /> <label for="filter-united_states">Unied States</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="filter-africa" value="Africa" /> <label for="filter-africa">Africa</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="filter-china" value="China" /> <label for="filter-china">China</label>
</div>
<button id="filter-button">Filter</button>

<table id="values-table" style="margin-top:20px;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Guide</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Languages</td>
    <td>Countries</td>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>Email</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="guide">JavaScript</td>
    <td class="category">Client Script</td>
    <td class="languages"><span class="language">English</span>, <span class="language">Spanish</span></td>
    <td class="countries"><span class="country">United States</span>, <span class="country">China</span></td>
    <td class="phone">555-555-5555</td>
    <td class="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="guide">PHP</td>
    <td class="category">Server Script</td>
    <td class="languages"><span class="language">English</span></td>
    <td class="countries"><span class="country">Africa</span></td>
    <td class="phone">555-555-5555</td>
    <td class="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="guide">ASP.net</td>
    <td class="category">Server Script</td>
    <td class="languages"><span class="language">Mandarin</span></td>
    <td class="countries"><span class="country">China</span></td>
    <td class="phone">555-555-5555</td>
    <td class="email"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Add a filter function when filter button is clicked:

```js
$("#filter-button").on("click", function(e){
    // Show all rows (in case any were hidden by a previous filtering)
    jQuery("#values-table > tr:hidden, #values-table > tbody > tr:hidden").show();
    // Get all filtered countries as array
    var selCountries = $("#country-filters input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
    if( selCountries.length < 1 ) {
        return; // No countries are selected!
    }
    // Loop through all table rows
    $("#values-table > tr, #values-table > tbody > tr").each(function(){
        // Loop through and return only rows that DO NOT contain a selected country and hide them
        $(this).filter(function(idx){
            return $(this).find("> td.countries > span.country")
                .filter(function(){return selCountries.indexOf($(this).text()) >= 0;}).length < 1;
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle of above code](https://jsfiddle.net/hwptewpc/2/)

Comment: Absolutely best answer. Thank you for your time. This is really what I was hopeing for. Finally, I can continue building my website. @Jim

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! @AdomasArabella

Answer (score -1):

I think you should find some library,because its not that easy as you think.
Here is big tablesorter library,maybe it will help you
http://tablesorter.com/docs/